# Nginx redirect all to subdirectory

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I am trying to redirect all requests coming to example.com to example.com/test, but I keep on getting "website redirected you too many times"

What I did.

```
location / {
    return 301 /test;
}
```

Can someone teach me how I could achieve something like this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you redirect it to /test the next time it matches the `location /` block again. `location /` matches all of your urls. What you need to do is add an equal sign so it just matches your base url.

```
location = / {
    return 301 /test;
}
```